# Google Identity Custom Login with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-signin, google-identity

With Google Sign-In, we are using a custom button skin (following the branding guidelines mentioned on https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button) and then calling to sign in manually from JS using essentially this:

```
gapi.load('auth2', function(){
    gapi.auth2.init().signIn().then(function(response) {
        // handle success
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // handle error/cancel
    });
});
```

I'm looking at the documentation for Google Identity and it appears neither of those (custom button or trigger sign-in via JS) is possible? Is there a way to do it, that I'm missing? We'd really like to be able to keep the Google sign-in button consistent with our other login buttons and handle UI-friendly resizing, etc. Thanks so much!

Note: I know that `google.accounts.id.prompt()` is in the documentation, but this doesn't appear to work universally. When I try it, I just get an `opt_out_or_no_session` error and nothing happens. Plus we'd like to use the Google button, rather than one tap, which is what I think this is for.

Comment: Exactly in the same boat.

Answer (score 4):

The new button supports a set of [visual data attributes](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/html-reference#visual-attributes) to choose from. This removes the need for you to host images and maintain branding guidelines. It helps users by ensuring that sign-in using Google looks and feels the same across sites -- consistency is good for everyone.

There is a [code generator](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/tools/configurator) that can be used to rapidly cycle through all the different size, shape, color, and text options for the sign-in button.

If you can't find attributes which meet your needs it would be great to hear more about what is lacking. If that still doesn't work you can continue with branding guidelines and directly call OpenID Connect endpoints to authenticate users.

If you only want to display the Sign In With Google button, set `data-auto_prompt="true"` to suppress One Tap. This isn't recommended as it increases the number of steps and friction on sign-in; One Tap improves sign-in rates.

Comment: What are the "OpenID Connect endpoints" you're referring to?

Comment: They're described [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect).  Google Identity Services new JavaScript library is described [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web). Directly calling the OpenID Connect endpoints means you'll manage the user flows and UX, using the new JS library means that you'll use the library offered by Google with optimized user flows.

Comment: Hmm that sounds rather complicated. We'll just put the Google UI inside a Google-specific login pop-up, so our base UI isn't restricted based on the limited Google UI options (ideally we'd be able to dynamically set the width, height, size, and corner radius, to make sure it matches our other login buttons, which respond to window resize).

Comment: Exactly, the JS SDK is offered to save you time, effort and need to understand OpenID in depth.  It would be interesting to hear if dynamic resizing affects CLS scores on your sign-up, sign-in pages or not.

Comment: This is a frustrating move on googles end. What was extremely clean and neat for our users (it basically WAS one-click login for most)... is not a hack-job this n that clumsy fallback mechanism for people who have disabled the annoying site-wide popups, but still want to sign in directly with google.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by doing something like this:

```js
const clientLoad = new Promise(resolve => {
  gapi.load('auth2', () => {
    resolve(gapi.auth2.init({ client_id: '<your_client_id>' }));
  });
});

async function login() {
  const client = await clientLoad;
  const response = client.signIn().catch((e) => {
    // in case user closes the popup
    if (e.error === 'popup_closed_by_user') {
      return null;
    }
    throw e;
  });

  // handle your authentication flow with the token received
  console.log(response.getAuthResponse());
}
```

And in your button:

```html
<button class="your-custom-style" onclick="login()">
  Login with google
</button>
```

Comment: This appears to use the old API (with which I had it working) and not the new API.

I ended up just putting the button inside a pop-up which is opened by our matching button. That way the design inside the pop-up matters less to our page.

Comment: Understood. The same issue here, but I will consider using Open ID :/

Answer (score 0):

when opt_out_or_no_session error happend, just login your google account in the browser,then such error disappered

Comment: `opt_out_or_no_session` also happens when users have adjusted their Chrome settings to stop the annoying upper-right auto-prompts across multiple websites. There still needs to be a fallback for manual login in this event, but googles new sign in system lacks such compatibility.